# Compile mysql client under cygwin with cmake

Tags: mysql, cygwin, compilation

I need a mysql-client for Eclipse Helios/Perl EPIC, running under windows7. Perl5.10 is running under cygwin on the same machine. I'm really strugglying to compile mysql sources with cmake under cygwin. I have also read the transition guide from ["configure" to "cmake"](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Autotools_to_CMake_Transition_Guide).

Here is the last test I tried among dozen of previous variants :

**Libraries and source Preparation** :

```
apt-cyg install make cmake gcc4-core gcc4-g++ libncurses-devel libncursesw-devel readline libstdc++6 libstdc++6-devel  
mkdir -p /usr/local/src  
mkdir -p /usr/local/mysql  
cd /usr/local/src  
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.9.tar.gz/from/http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/mysql/  
find . -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -exec tar -zxvf {} \;  
find . -type d -name "mysql-*" -exec cd {} \;
```

**Build/Install**

```
CC=gcc; CFLAGS=-O3 ; CXX=gcc ; CXXFLAGS=-O3; export CC CFLAGS CXX CXXFLAGS  

cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql -DWITH_EMBEDDED_SERVER=0 -DWITH_LIBEDIT=0 -DISABLE_SHARED=1
```

**Build is stopped** at 86% with

```
[ 86%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/mysqld.dir/main.cc.o  
Linking CXX executable mysqld.exe  
Creating library file: libmysqld.dll.a  
libsql.a(mysqld.cc.o):mysqld.cc:(.rdata$_ZTV12Comp_creator[vtable for Comp_creator]+0x10): undefined reference to `___cxa_pure_virtual'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make[2]: *** [sql/mysqld.exe] Error 1  
make[1]: *** [sql/CMakeFiles/mysqld.dir/all] Error 2
```

I read 100's of threads but blindly as lacking compilation skills.

Maybe is there also an alternative or better solution to run my existing mysql debugging server hosted in a Debian's VM (as guest on my windows machine) from Eclipse.. ?

Suggestions are more than welcome.

Thx in advance

Comment: I have the same configuration as yours and I would like to the same things.(i.e. made requests on MySQl DB using perl installed with cygwin)
But I still have the same errors Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.dll Did you succeed to solve your problem ? best regards

Comment: Sorry, no I gave it up and I'm running VM's.

Comment: I am using perl5.14 and while trying to compile mysql source version 5.5.21, stumbled here as well. Ended up using binaries from an old distribution of mysql, which still was using ./configure script. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hum, looks like that there is no absolute need to do that to use perl epic with Eclipse, as cygwin perl embeds already the DBI modules (to be loaded with CPAN). So it's a way to get around this problem.